# How do I wildcard match a class name inside querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have bunch of rows under `foo bar row-id*` class name pattern. How do I match all rows under that pattern using querySelectorAll?

```
document.querySelectorAll(".foo.bar.[=*row-id]")
```

This doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[class^="foo bar row-id"]` will match what you're looking for. This searches for all class staring with `.foo bar row-id`. You can swap `class` for any other HTML attribute as well.

`[class$="foo bar row-id"]` will match `class` ending with your query.

`[class*="foo bar row-id"]` will match all class that contains your query.

Example:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="foo bar row-id"]');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if there is another class name after the row-id?

Comment: @jeffbRTC Hmm just trying to get some clarification. In the example let's say you have some elements with the classes `foo bar row-id-1 class-1`, `foo bar row-id-2 class-1` and `foo bar row-id-3 class-2`. You'd want to find all with the `class-1` present?

Comment: Let's just say it's `foo bar row-id-2 someClass`. So, I want to apply the * to the row-id only but also match someClass..

Comment: You are able to combine multiple selectors. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works#Combining_Selectors)

Example `document.querySelectorAll('[class^="foo bar row-id"][class*="someclass"]')`